# Discrete math question - is the statement true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove:  $\forall \{n, m\}$, if $n$ is even and $m$ is odd, then $3 n + 2 m$ is even.

Comment: Seems pretty trivial ... unless you have to do one of those really precise proofs, with definitional axioms for even-ness, etc. Is that what you are being asked to do?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This is absurdly easy.   Is $3(2k) + 2(2m+1)$ even or odd or is it impossible to tell?

Answer (score 0):

Because $3 n$ is even and $2 m$ is even.